# Get remote url of an artifact

Tags: maven, nexus, nexus3

Is there a way to get the the remote url of an artifact stored by Nexus 3 OSS? Or even the id of the repo if a group is used.

I tried with the REST APIs but there isn't what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to create a maven plugin that lists remote urls of every dependency in a project.

### Example:

**org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1** -----> `http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar`

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for?  Or what you're not looking for (e.g what REST doesn't do)?  I don't want to answer then not help:P

Comment: @joedragons: I added an example. Obviously for maven the download url is `http://my-nexus-server/public/...`. Only nexus can know the remote url, if it is stored somewhere.

Comment: The reason this plugin doesnt exist yet is because it would bring no information : the root url is constant (you can see it in your "<mirrors>" maven settings), and about the variable part, you can see it in any dependency tree.

Comment: @Tristan: infact I want to get this info from nexus.

Comment: @Tristan: I know the url of the artifact in my nexus repository, I need the remote repo url.

Comment: Ok, but it looks like the information u need is not rly dynamic, it's just Nexus settings. So there is no real reason Nexus would expose these informations as REST api.

Comment: @Tristan: no if you use group repos. Suppose you have two proxy repos (codehaus and jboss for instance) and you create a group repo for the two. When maven queries nexus for an artifact, nexus tries to downoad it from codehaus. If codehaus does not have such artifact then tries with jboss. I cannot infer the download url upfront. Infact in my question I asked a way to get the repo's id if there was no way to get the remote url directly

Comment: Ok, but I was not thinking about getting all the exact informations, I was thinking about the goal of getting them. The only goal I can see is to allow developers to compile the project easily from a network where they can't access Nexus, so the static informations about all the alternative repos used by Nexus (which should be a short list) should be enough IMO.